# PHP variable used in SQL

Tags: php, sql

My code checks if there is $GET value, if not then assign ALL values of array.
Seems like simple thing,not sure why its not working.

```
if(isset($_GET["smonth"])) {$smonth= $_GET["smonth"];
} 
else {$smonth =12;}  working , but not what I want
else {$smonth =array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) ;}
```

After that I would like to use it in SQL :

```
and d.month_of_year = '".$smonth."%'
```

That would be something like

```
 and month_of_year = (all values of array) or 1 value)
```

My Question:
What would be best solution to check, if active month is available? If not, assign All months to query.Thank You

Comment: do you want to query by the current month of the year

Answer (score 0):

The built-in PHP functions of in_array and implode should solve your issue:

```
in_array('1', $_GET["smonth"]); // checks if January is in $_GET["smonth"]
implode("," , $_GET["smonth"]); // Pull all of the values out of $_GET["smonth"] as a A STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your statement `and d.month_of_year IN (" . implode(',', $smonth) . ")`

Comment: Yes, because implode concatenates an array. So if you have an single month, you have to store it also in an array.

Answer (score 0):

`=` operator checks for single value. If you want to check multiple values, use `in`.

```
and d.month_of_year in (".$smonth.")
```

You also have a `%` there, which works with `LIKE` queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_GET['month'])){
    $month =  date('m');  //This would give you the index of the current month.

    $array = array('01','02','02');

    $query = "select * from table where month = ";
    if(in_array($month,$array)){
        $query = "select * from table where month = '".$month."'";

        //Then query here
    }
    else
    {
    $query = "select * from table";
        $where = "";
        foreach($month as $m){
            $where .= ' month = "'.$m.'" and ';
        }

        //There would be a ending and pls just try remove it

        $query .= $where;

        // then query here
        }


    }
?>
```